# How can I correctly build a query to get the fields of an object I need from the database?

Tags: apex, soql, response

I am saving a new object to the database and I want to get information back in the form of the values ​​of specific fields of this object. How can I build a request correctly? This code only returns these fields:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Contact createContact(Contact newContact){
    upsert newContact;
    return newContact;
}
```

// responce

```
Contact:{Email=asads@wrer.com, FirstName=xczcz, LastName=zxczxc, Contact_Level__c=Secondary, Id=0035g000003gV6OAAU}
```

I need these fields:

```
Name, Email, Contact_Level__c, Account.Name, Owner.Name, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate
```

Tried to rebuild the query, but I got errors, can't save it, incorrect syntax ...

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Contact createContact(Contact newContact){
    upsert newContact;
    return [SELECT  Name, Email, Contact_Level__c, Account.Name, Owner.Name, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate
            FROM  Contact WHERE Id = newContact.Id];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a binding by prefixing the reference to newContact.Id using a colon:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Contact createContact(Contact newContact){
    upsert newContact;
    return [SELECT  Name, Email, Contact_Level__c, Account.Name, Owner.Name, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate
            FROM  Contact WHERE Id = :newContact.Id];
}
```

Comment: Pro-tip: you don't need to access the zeroth index. As long as a query returns exactly one row, it's legal to assign it to a scalar value (e.g. as a return value).

Comment: Fair enough, and in this case there is no fear of an empty response either. I will remove that part.